# Google One Tap Login with custom term of use

Tags: google-authentication, google-signin, google-one-tap

I am using google one-tap login for my web application.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in

This one-tap login is replacing the custom sign-up form I used to have.

While the concept is a "one-tap" login, it is missing the term of use agreement.

The old sign-up form contained validation of the term-of-use agreement.

Now I wonder if I can move to google one-tap login with my custom term-of-use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found that on the on-tap login popup, there is a link to the `/policy` route of your web application.

The policy / term of use can be displayed on this route.